# Javascript code for pushing input from 3 different arrays to the fourth array to output put "My fullname is '' " and I live in ""

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying resolve the problem where you have three different arrays. The first array has first names stored, second array has last name stored, and the third array has place name stored. The fourth array supposed to have elements combining the corresponding first names, last names, and places in the following format "May name is (first name and last name) and I live in (place). I am trying it in Javascript.If I am making three loops with i, j, k starting with 0 and looping thru length of the array, it is printing too many of the elements for the fourth array. I know I am doing wrong, but just cannot find out a different approach. Please help.

Comment: hint: you need just one loop, then take out the values at that iterated index from all the different arrays.

Comment: Please show the code you've attempted; otherwise there's no way for us to tell what's wrong with it or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: You need just one loop, that takes out the values at that iterated index (`index`) from all the arrays like:

```
firstName[index]
lastName[index] 
locations[index]
```

---

**Note**: Keep in mind that all the arrays **MUST** have the same number of elements inside. Otherwise you go with "undefined"-errors.

Maybe try this solution:

```js
let firstName = ["Peter", "Kevin", "Julia"]
let lastName = ["Maffay", "Alone", "Peterson"]
let locations = ["Munich", "Berlin", "Stuttgart"]

let result = []

for (let index=0; index<firstName.length; index++) {
  let quote = `My name is ${firstName[index]} ${lastName[index]} and I live in ${locations[index]}.`
  result.push(quote)
}

console.log(result)
```